# isosurface function MATLAB usage

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

Hi can any one give me a simple example of how to use the isosurface function in MATLAB. 
The example given if you type `help isosurface` is quite confusing. Searching on google did not help as no one gives simple examples anywhere. All of them use predefined functions like 
`flow`.

For starters, suppose i have points `(x,y,z)` where z=0 and at each point I define a constant 
function `f(x,y,z)=6`. So if I use the isosurface function on the isovalue `6` I would like MATLAB to give me a 3d plot with the XY plane highlighted in some colour, say green.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you gave is very uninteresting, in fact maybe even problematic.

By collapsing all points to `z=0,` you no longer can/need to use [ISOSURFACE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isosurface.html), and [CONTOUR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html) should be called instead. Even then, a constant function `f(X,Y)=6` won't show anything either...

Since [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681278/isosurface-function-matlab-usage/7681443#7681443) already showed how to use ISOSURFACE, here is an example for the CONTOUR function:

```
%# create a function to apply to all X/Y coordinates
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:0.1:2,-1:0.1:1);
f = @(X,Y) X.^3 -2*Y.^2 -3*X;

%# plot the function surface
subplot(121), surfc(X,Y,f(X,Y))
axis equal, daspect([1 1 3])

%# plot the iso-contour corresponding to where f=-1
subplot(122), contour(X,Y,f(X,Y),[-1 -1]), 
axis square, title('Contour where f(X,Y)=-1')
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I don't quite understand your example, but here's how you use `isosurface` to draw a sphere:

```
%# create coordinates
[xx,yy,zz] = meshgrid(-15:15,-15:15,-15:15);
%# calculate distance from center of the cube
rr = sqrt(xx.^2 + yy.^2 + zz.^2);

%# create the isosurface by thresholding at a iso-value of 10
isosurface(xx,yy,zz,rr,10);

%# make sure it will look like a sphere
axis equal
```

[image]